# Replace multiple string items in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that shows this value "135_1,undefined,undefined"

I have to find the "undefined" in the above array  and then replace it with "0_0".Undefined can occur multiple times in the array.

I used

```
 var extra = myVariable.replace("undefined", "0_0");
    alert(extra);
```

but then I have to use this three times so that every single time it can search one and replace it.

I have also used this::

```
  for (var i = 0; i < myVariable.length; i++) {
        alert(myVariable[i]);
        myVariable[i] = myVariable[i].replace(/undefined/g, '0_0');
    }
    alert(myVariable);
```

but it did'nt solved my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.replace` is a method accessible to strings. `undefined` is not a string.

This might help you.

```
for (var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === undefined) {
    arr[i] = "0_0";
  }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

---

You could also use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this. Note, it only works in `IE >= 9`

```
arr = arr.map(function(elem) {
  return elem === undefined ? "0_0" : elem;
});
```

Comment: Or else using arr.map().

Comment: @Scimonster, thanks, I was just writing up a `.map` example. I had to check which version of IE supported it before offering it as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) you can use [`$.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var extra = $.map(myVariable, function(item) {
    return item || '0_0';
}
```

This will return a new array whereby each item comprising (in your case) an empty string or `undefined` is replaced by `'0_0'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['135_1',undefined,undefined];
while(arr.indexOf(undefined) != -1) {
    pos=arr.indexOf(undefined);
    arr[pos]='0_0';
}
```